# Is it possible to select an element inside shown list using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a list:

```
<div class="ressources" *ngFor="let ressource of ressources">
      <div class="ressource">
        <h2 class="ressourceReferenceClient">{{ressource.referenceClient}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNom">{{ressource.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourcePrenom">{{ressource.prenom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceEquipe">{{ressource.Equipe.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNbCompetence">{{ressource.getCompetence().length}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActif">{{ressource.isActif()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActifAsBackUp">{{ressource.isActifAsBackUp}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateEntree">{{ressource.getDateEntree()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateSortie">{{ressource.getDateSortie()}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

where i can select an item in this list and then send the information recovered from this item to another page using a button.
Is it possible?
And can you give me some advices to realize it, i'm actually learning angular.

Comment: hi, So, basically you want to create a dropdown menu from which you can select an option and you want to send that selected value to another page?

Comment: i want to display a list and then be able to select a displayed element and send it to another page, for example: to edit the informations of this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understand you, you are doing this steps (see comments to the code):

```
<div class="ressources" *ngFor="let ressource of ressources"> // creating multiple divs with class ressources
      <div class="ressource">
        <h2 class="ressourceReferenceClient">{{ressource.referenceClient}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNom">{{ressource.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourcePrenom">{{ressource.prenom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceEquipe">{{ressource.Equipe.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNbCompetence">{{ressource.getCompetence().length}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActif">{{ressource.isActif()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActifAsBackUp">{{ressource.isActifAsBackUp}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateEntree">{{ressource.getDateEntree()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateSortie">{{ressource.getDateSortie()}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What you can do is add a click event, where you pass the ressource object to your method inside the component. For example like this:

```
<div class="ressources" *ngFor="let ressource of ressources"> // creating multiple divs with class ressources
      <div class="ressource" (click)="yourMethod(ressource)"> // click event here
        <h2 class="ressourceReferenceClient">{{ressource.referenceClient}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNom">{{ressource.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourcePrenom">{{ressource.prenom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceEquipe">{{ressource.Equipe.nom}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceNbCompetence">{{ressource.getCompetence().length}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActif">{{ressource.isActif()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceActifAsBackUp">{{ressource.isActifAsBackUp}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateEntree">{{ressource.getDateEntree()}}</h2>
        <h2 class="ressourceDateSortie">{{ressource.getDateSortie()}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then inside your component ts file you can do something like this:

```
@ViewChild(Child) childElement:Child;; // this is the component you want to pass the data to it is a child component
```

inside your method

```
yourMethod(ressources: any){
this.childElement.methodToParseTheRessource(ressources); // this method has to be defined in your child component
}
```

If you want to pass values from child to parent, investigate the @Output option in Angular. You can read more about them here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example.

Otherwise I suggest going through a tutorial to understand the basics of how angular components works. Hope this helps.